# php - Laravel framework MassAssignmentException During Seed Data

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, seed

I have got following issue during seed data in laravel framework.

```
php artisan db:seed --class=LevelsTableSeeder

[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException]
level
```

My seed file(LevelsTableSeeder.php) as follows.

```
   <?php 
    use App\Models\Levels;
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    class LevelsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
        public function run()
        {
            $levels = [
                 ['level'=>1,  'xp_second'=>0.101, 'xp_hour'=>365.220],
                 ['level'=>2,  'xp_second'=>0.104, 'xp_hour'=>365.220]
            ];
            foreach($levels as $level) {
                Levels::create($level);
            }
            $this->command->info('Levels seeded :-)');
        }
    }
```

And my Levels model file as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cache;

class Levels extends Model {

    protected $table = 'levels';

    public function maxLevel()
    {
        return Cache::get('levels_max_level', function() {
            return parent::max('level');
        });
    }
}
```

Could you help me?
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The MassAssignmentException is thrown whenever you try to assign multiple fields in a Model and then create it in a database. In order to protect your database, the Eloquent library offers you the Mass Assignment Protection, which means only fields you allow to be mass assigned will be accepted.

[Laravel 5.2 Documentation for Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Add to your Model the attribute `protected $fillable` with an array of fields you are interested in mass assigning:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cache;

class Levels extends Model {

    protected $table = 'levels';
    protected $fillable = ['level', 'xp_second', 'xp_hour'];

    public function maxLevel()
    {
        return Cache::get('levels_max_level', function() {
            return parent::max('level');
        });
    }
}
```

Another way to solve this issue is to unguard your model by calling `Levels::unguard()` from your Seeder Class. That way you will disable the Guard that protects your model from being mass assigned.

```
 <?php 
    use App\Models\Levels;
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    class LevelsTableSeeder extends Seeder {
        public function run()
        {
            Levels::unguard();   // to unguard your model
            $levels = [
                 ['level'=>1,  'xp_second'=>0.101, 'xp_hour'=>365.220],
                 ['level'=>2,  'xp_second'=>0.104, 'xp_hour'=>365.220]
            ];
            foreach($levels as $level) {
                Levels::create($level);
            }
            $this->command->info('Levels seeded :-)');
            Levels::guard(); // To guard back
        }
    }
```

This is an acceptable solution for seeding purposes, but not recommended on controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment), Laravel provides protection from Mass Assignment vulnerabilities and so you actually have to tell Laravel which fields are mass assignable inside your model, using the `$fillable` property:

```
class Levels extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['level', 'xp_second', 'xp_hour'];

}
```